# CSS3 transition working only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, transition

How can I make this transition work in all browsers? It functions only in Chrome despite the fact that I applied the values to work on all the browsers. (I also tried it on other computers but I got the same result):

```
.titlu 
{ 
    background:url(images/titlu.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:716px; 
    height: 237px; 
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    top:460px; 
    right: 255px; 
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.20s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.20s linear;
    -o-transition: background 0.20s linear;
    transition: background 0.20s linear;
}

.titlu:hover 
{
    width:716px; 
    height: 237px;
    display: block; 
    z-index: 5; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image:url(images/titlu2.png);
}
```

I have been ask to specify the problem more detailed... What I meant by not working was that the webkit effect doesn't apply to the image...The hover works just that the transition doesn't take effect.

Comment: 1) apply the transition to the `background-image` only. `transition: background-image .2s linear;` 2) "Not working" doesn't tell us much, if anything. What specifically is the problem?

Comment: I know that Javascript will do the job but I prefer using CSS3. Anyway if you know a easy way to achive the same effect but stay simple in the same time feel free to help :)

Comment: @Shmiddty - I already tried that and it is still not working. I specified the problem more cleary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, cross-fading images only works in Chrome 18+, iOS6 (maybe other WebKit browsers? doesn't work in Safari on Win 7 though...) for now. What you could do in order to emulate the same effect is set the second image on an absolutely positioned child (and the reason I am saying child and not pseudo-element is that transitions on pseudo-elements don't yet work in other browsers except Firefox) that occupies the same space as the parent and change the `opacity` of that child from `0` to `1` on hover on the parent.

## [*demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/dsIAg)

**HTML**:

```
<h1 class='titlu'>
  <div class='secondary-bg'></div>
</h1>
```

**CSS**:

```
.titlu { 
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2013-06-a-web.jpg) 
              no-repeat; 
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 16em; 
  height: 10em; 
}
.secondary-bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit; height: inherit;
  opacity: 0;
  background: inherit;
  background-image: 
    url(http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2010-13-a-web.jpg);
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
.titlu:hover .secondary-bg { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: Optionally, it may be possible to use `:before` (or `:after`) for the alternate image rather than a separate HTML element, in combination with `.titlu:hover:before` or `.titlu:hover`.

Comment: That would be great if transitions on pseudo-elements worked in other browsers except Firefox.